# How to execute custom ant target using exec task?

Tags: ant

In our project we are using a proprietary product which contains its own custom ant executable to build the deployment artifact.
So, we have two build files 'build-artifcat.xml' and 'build.xml'.
Here,
'build-artifcat.xml' - contains ant targets which can be executed with this products custom ant executable.
'build.xml' - contains ant targets which can be executed by Apache Ant.

We are using Bamboo CICD tool and this tool provides facility to execute only Apache Ant targets.
So, we are planning to use  task to invoke ant targets from 'build-artifcat.xml' using this products custom ant executable.

I found below code while checking older projects but here I am not sure how can I specify the target to be executed from from 'build-artifcat.xml'.
Can you please help.

```
   <target name="buildArtifact">
      <echo>Running ant exec: ${run.custom.ant.exec}</echo>
      <exec dir="${run.ant.exec.dir}" executable="${run.custom.ant.exec}" error="${basedir}/${error.log.file}">
        <arg value="-f" />
        <arg file="${basedir}/build-artifcat.xml" />
        <arg value="-DimportDir=${import.location}" />
        <arg value="-DartifactDir=${artifact.dir}" />
        <arg value="-data" />
        <arg value="${temp.workspace}" />
        <arg value="-vmargs" />
        <arg value="-Xmx1024m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=./crashes/my-heap-dump.hprof -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -Xloggc:./crashes/gc.log" />
        <arg value="-verbose" />
      </exec>
   </target>
```

Comment: Normally the target is specified on the ant command line after optional args, so you would just need to add one more arg at the end of the list `<arg value="target_name" />`

Comment: Yes, I was about to update the same. It worked after simply passing target name like <arg value="target_name" /> at the end of the list. You can post this as an answer.